# Laravel 4 with Require JS throws Net tab error

Tags: javascript, laravel, requirejs, laravel-4

In my Net tab and console in firefox I am getting an error because that URL isn't a valid URL.  I'm not sure where this URL is coming from.  Is require.js making this POST request?  Any ideas on how to fix this?

"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://admin.localhost/%3C?php%20echo%20HTTP_PATH%20?%3EcategoryList"

Comment: Do you think this is valid url `http://admin.localhost/<?php echo HTTP_PATH ?>categoryList`?

Comment: No, I don't.  I don't know why that URL is being sent.

Comment: how did you configure `require.js` with `laravel`?